# how to move the div in the second 'col-sm-6' to the first 'col-sm-6'? (moving search box to the left side)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery Datatable and need to move search box to the far left side. To do that, I need to first move the class **dataTables_filter** to the first **<div class="col-sm-6>"** and left aligned.
How do I achieve that with Jquery? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: [This example](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/42453/move-search-text-box-to-left-side) from the DataTables forum works (I tested it) and may meet your needs, or it may give you an approach that you can adapt (it does not use jQuery to make the changes).

Comment: The only thing I would do differently is add the `ip` back to the `dom` option: `dom:"<'myfilter'f><'mylength'l>tip"`. This will ensure the information and pagination sections are displayed. See [`dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) for details.